# React not updating state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I am creating a simple chance dice game using jsx functional components, however when I click a button that creates a roll it displays the post state. Here is my code for the component (reduced un-necessary code), fairly new to coding so excuse if it is a bit rough. Also here is an example of it happening: https://gyazo.com/3f708e053a361e85e9b91d84b3e1849b

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

...

const Dice = () => {


    // Declare state
    const [gameState, setState] = useState("roll");
    const [randomRoll, setRandom] = useState(13.37);
    const [rollSep, setRollSep] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0]);

    // Roll the dice animation
    const roll = () => {
        setState("Rolling...");


        setTimeout(() => {

            setRandom(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / (1 * 100))
            setState("Rolled " + randomRoll);

        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Box>

                ...

                {animationState === "blitz" ? (
                    <StyledBlitz transform={`translateX(${randomRoll}%)`}>
                        <h2>{randomRoll}</h2>
                        <img src={dice} alt="dice" />
                    </StyledBlitz>
                ) : null}

                ...

                <Button
                    onClick={roll}
                >
                    {gameState}
                </Button>

            </Box>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Dice;
```